# converting a dataframe with array columns to a long dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have columns which are arrays in spark DataFrame. I want to convert the dataframe to a long dataframe where each element of the array is in a new row.
I want it to be like the one below.

eg.

```
spark.createDataFrame([(['abcd','cdf','dfg'],['123']),(['a'],['45','67',98'])],['s','d']).show()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode`

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(['abcd','cdf','dfg'],['123']),(['a'],['45','67','98'])],['s','d'])

df.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl")

spark.sql("select x, y from tbl lateral view explode(s) v1 as x lateral view explode(d) v2 as y").show()

+----+---+
|   x|  y|
+----+---+
|abcd|123|
| cdf|123|
| dfg|123|
|   a| 45|
|   a| 67|
|   a| 98|
+----+---+
```